# creating multiple instances of firebase in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to initialize two different firebase apps and export them .
I tried creating a different file with somrthing similar to this and exporting it .
How do we actully create two instances at the same time ?
Any reference to any blog would be of great help as I couldn't get the right one .

Editing it for making it clear.
I need to listen to another firebase which is API.FIREBASE_XYZCONFIG

```
import API from "../api";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";


firebase.initializeApp(API.FIREBASE_CONFIG);

const firestore = firebase.firestore();
firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

export default firestore;
```

This is how it has been done in one of those file and exported .
What I did is

```
import API from "../api";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

//import broadcastfirestore from './broadcastindex.js'

const a= firebase.initializeApp(API.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
const b= firebase.initializeApp(API.FIREBASE_BROADCAST_CONFIG,'broadcast');

const firestore = a.firestore();
const firestore2= b.firestore();
firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

export default firestore;
```

Is the above method correct for initializing ?

Comment: Do you mean `collection`?

Answer (score 1):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#multiple-projects .

```
// Initialize Firebase with a default Firebase project
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firebase with a second Firebase project
var otherProject = firebase.initializeApp(otherProjectFirebaseConfig, "other");

console.log(firebase.app().name);  // "[DEFAULT]"
console.log(otherProject.name);    // "otherProject"

// Use the shorthand notation to access the default project's Firebase services
var defaultStorage = firebase.storage();
var defaultFirestore = firebase.firestore();

// Use the otherProject variable to access the second project's Firebase services
var otherStorage = otherProject.storage();
var otherFirestore = otherProject.firestore();
```